# Boost Regex Submatches Empty on Some Machines

Tags: c++, regex, linux, boost

I am using the boost regex library in my code. I have a simple application that compiles and runs correctly on a machine that is running Fedora. When I compile the same code on SUSE linux, all but the first submatch string is empty.

The code is as follows

```
const string pattern = "(abc)(def)"; 
const string target = "abcdef";

boost::regex regexPattern(pattern, boost::regex::extended);
boost::smatch what;

bool isMatchFound = boost::regex_match(target, what, regexPattern);
if (isMatchFound)
{
    for (unsigned int i=0; i < what.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << "WHAT " << i << " " << what[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

The output on fedora is the following

```
WHAT 0 abcdef
WHAT 1 abc
WHAT 2 def
```

The output on SUSE is the following

```
WHAT 0 abcdef
WHAT 1 
WHAT 2
```

I cannot seem to find any reference to a similar problem anywhere. I assume there is a simple fix, but I havent been able to find it despite days of scouring the web.

The compilers have the following versions.

Fedora : g++ (GCC) 4.5.1 20100924 (Red Hat 4.5.1-4)
SUSE : g++ (GCC) 4.1.2 20070115 (SUSE Linux)

I am using Boost version 1.48.0 in both cases. I don't have root on either machine.

Comment: I would assume that somehow extended regexp syntax does not work under gcc 4.1.2

Comment: I had the same suspicion, although since I don't have root its a tough option test. I'm guessing im just going to have to try and push a request through to update the compiler. Last time I asked I was literally laughed at lol.

Comment: On a side note a match is still correctly detected and three submatches are returned indicating that the library is partially working, its just that two of the submatches are incorrectly returned as the empty string.

Comment: It's probably not the compiler per se that is problematic-- it's almost certainly one of the libraries that comes along with the SDK.  If that's the case, you can find the source to said library, compile it yourself, and link with it statically to preclude use of the stock shared library-- all without needing to "have root".

Comment: I do compile boost myself, and I suspect it is just using the GNU regex lib under the hood in linux. I suppose I could confirm that by rewriting the function to use that instead to verify the same problem exists. That is unless you are referring to me compiling the GNU libraries used by boost from source, which I do not do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the compiler to a later version fixed the issue. I am suprised compiling boost with the older 4.1 compiler silently broke the submatch functionality on that SUSE box.